# Typescript: Can't return child class instance from super class' function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having trouble returning a child class object from a super class function. I have the following structure:

**pizza.ts:**

```
import { PineapplePizza } from './pineapple.pizza';

export class Pizza {
    public putOn(Pineapple pineapple): Pizza {
        // ...
        return new PineapplePizza(pineapple);
        // ...
    }
}
```

**pineapple.pizza.ts:**

```
import { Pizza } from './pizza';

export class PineapplePizza extends Pizza {
    // ...
}
```

But I keep getting this runtime error:

**firefox:**

> ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'Pizza' before initialization

**chrome:**

> ReferenceError: 'Pizza' is not defined

Does anyone know how to fix that? Or is impossible to return a child class instance from a super class?

**EDIT #1:**

This might be due to circular importing. Is there a way to pre-declare a class, kind of like with `c++`? Or a way to control which file gets compiled first?

Comment: Yes, this is due to the circular dependency. `Pizza` must be initialised first, before `class extends Pizza` is evaluated

Comment: You can fix this by changing your imports, but better refactor your code so that the superclass does not depend on the subclass.

Comment: @Bergi (1) At this point I am not importing those files anywhere and I'm still getting the error. (2) The problem is that I need to return exactly that type (PineapplePizza). Is there any workaround?

Comment: If you aren't importing them, the modules don't get loaded and evaluated, and won't throw the error.

Comment: @Bergi Right... I'm importing only the Pizza file somewhere else. The PineapplePizza one is only imported by Pizza. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. The easiest choice would be to put the `PineapplePizza` class inside the same module, *after* the `Pizza` definition.